# ASP.NET MVC : Posting both, Id and Value of the value selected in the drop-down

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

The other dropdowns are populated based on the selection of the Material. Currently, I'm binding the dropdown to MaterialID and then querying the dbcontext in the controller to get the corresponding the MaterialName. I don't want to post **only** MaterialName because I have a javascript to post back the MaterialId to get values for cascading drop-downs.

How can I post both, the MaterialId and the corresponding MaterialName when I select a value from the dropdown list and submit the form? Is it even possible?

**Controller snippet**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.MaterialList = new SelectList(db.Materials, "MaterialId", "MaterialName");
    Material material = new Material();
    material.MaterialCollection = db.Materials.ToList<Material>();
...
}


[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Plate plate)
        {
            try
            {
                var mname = db.Materials.Where(x => x.MaterialId == plate.Material.MaterialId).ToList();
                plate.Material.MaterialName = mname[0].MaterialName;
...
}
```

**EF Model Material.cs**

```
namespace WebApp.Models.EFModels
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class Material
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Material()
        {
            this.Lengths = new HashSet<Length>();
            this.Widths = new HashSet<Width>();
            this.Thicknesses = new HashSet<Thickness>();
        }

        public int MaterialId { get; set; }
        public string MaterialName { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Length> Lengths { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Width> Widths { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Thickness> Thicknesses { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<Material> MaterialCollection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View snippet**

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Material.MaterialId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-5">
                @if (ViewBag.MaterialList != null)
                {
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Material.MaterialId,
                         ViewBag.MaterialList as SelectList,
                         "Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
                }
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Material.MaterialId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Only if you were to include an additional input for it and use javascript to set its value based on the selected option. But why do think you want to do this? If you need the name based on the ID in the POST method, just query the database again

Comment: @StephenMuecke - because there is a one-to-many relation between MaterialId and the values for other drop-downs, which in turn are the condition for populating other drop-downs.

Comment: But what does that have to do with the `MaterialName` property? (all you need for that is the `MaterialId` property which you already have)

Comment: Not really for Material. I want to post both, Id and Value for the other drop-downs. I just didn't want to post the whole code.

Comment: What other dropdowns are you referring to?

Comment: Cascading dropdowns and dependency (parent--> child)


1 ) MaterialId --> Length (single value) 2) MaterialId --> Width (single value) 3) MaterialId --> Thickness (multiple values) 4) ThicknessId --> edge space (multiple values) 5) EdgeSpaceId --> ... (multiple values)

Comment: There is nothing in your question relating to code for cascading dropdownlists! And Your `MaterialName` should have nothing at all to do with that anyway

Comment: If there was a way to do it for one dropdown (Material), I'd use the similar method for other dropdowns.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that?

Comment: Suppose I select Thickness from the dropdown list, and depending on that I populate "Edge Space" dropdown, A single ThicknessId maps to multiple values for EdgeSpace, how do I know the selected value in the controller?

Comment: I suggest you study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym) to understand how to implement cacscding dropdownlists correctly

Comment: Ah, Thanks! I think I'm missing on something. I'll update you.